# Can't upgrade from 15.10 to 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, 15.10

When I try to upgrade to 16.04 by running...

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

...I see a lot of messages about broken items, starting with libnss3-nssdb...

```
 Investigating (0) libnss3-nssdb [ amd64 ] < 2:3.23-0ubuntu0.15.10.1 > ( admin )
    Broken libnss3-nssdb:amd64 Depends on libnss3 [ amd64 ] < 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 > ( libs ) (= 2:3.23-0ubuntu0.15.10.1)
      Considering libnss3:amd64 46 as a solution to libnss3-nssdb:amd64 11
Removing libnss3-nssdb:amd64 rather than change libnss3:amd64
```

There are many other lines like this, and the first few reference libnss3.  I also was getting [an error re: libnss3 any time I try upgrading or installing a package with apt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986265/how-to-fix-unmet-dependency), which is what has prompted me to attempt the upgrade to 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Are there things you need on 15.10? If not perhaps a fresh install of 16.04 might be in order!

Comment: George, that is not a terrible idea.  I may go that route.  Though I would have a substantial amount of software to reinstall, databases to import, etc.

Comment: Run this first `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` thenn try the upgrade again

Comment: No such luck:  `root@my-desktop:~# apt dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnss3-nssdb : Depends: libnss3 (= 2:3.23-0ubuntu0.15.10.1) but 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.`

Comment: Please don't expect there to be a single command to solve your issue lets correct them one at a time, run `sudo apt-get install -f`, then try again!

Comment: George, I did run that command but I got a similar result.  `root@my-desktop:~# apt install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnss3-nssdb : Depends: libnss3 (= 2:3.23-0ubuntu0.15.10.1) but 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies`

Comment: Now do `sudo dpkg --configure -a` again

Comment: Ok, I did that.  I then repeated some of the other commands.  I always get a message that references libnss3-nssdb.

Comment: I went ahead and did a fresh install of 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Ok usually a better strategy IMO...

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the dependency version.

Try using:

`sudo apt-get install libnss3=2:3.23-0ubuntu0.15.10.1`